# How can i use onclick of button from jquery.html() in vue.js

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js, onclick, render

I tried to use `@click` and `v-on:click` for a button `$('#div').html('buttoncode');` but it's not working.

```html
<div id="boxBtn1">
  <button type="submit" v-on:click="btn1Click()">Export Excel</button>
</div>


var html = '<a id="a1" href="#" v-on:click="mymethod()">Download Report</a>';
$('#boxBtn1').html(html);
```

But mymethod() not working
I solved my problem this way 
but I don't think it's the best way. 
Can you help guide me to the correct way please.

```html
btn1Click() {
   var html = '<a id="a1" href="'+response.data+'">A1Button</a>';
   $('#boxBtn1').html(html);

   $('#a1').click(function() {
     alert('a1 click');
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Why not write your own method that emulates this function?

Comment: Firstly, there isn't a div with the id of `div`. I'm not very familiar with jQuery but I think that's what the selector in your first sentence is looking for.... It won't find anything. Secondly, there's no reason to use jQuery with Vue - plain JavaScript will work just fine. And I don't think injecting HTML in this way is a good idea in Vue. Just use a v-if flag or something like that, and use the button to toggle whatever that flag is pointing to.